# Python: SSLError, bad handshake, Unexpected EOF em get request

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests

Estou tentando fazer um get request em um site específico, porém estou tendo problemas com o erro listado abaixo.

**Meu código:**

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.beneficiossociais.caixa.gov.br/consulta/beneficio/04.01.00-00_00.asp'
r = requests.get(url, verify=False)
```

**O erro:**:

> SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.beneficiossociais.caixa.gov.br', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /consulta/beneficio/04.01.00-00_00.asp (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: SysCallError(-1, 'Unexpected EOF')")))

Comment: Para acessar a página de beneficio você tem que passar pelo formulário de consulta para obter um token de acesso.

Comment: Mas essa resquest em si é só um get para me retornar o HTML da página sem a consulta do formulário.

Comment: O servidor só lhe entrega a página se tiver o token.

Comment: Tenta obter a documentação da  API no [Dataprev](https://portal.dataprev.gov.br/solucao)

Comment: Provavelmente você esta usando proxy na rede ou em algum lugar o que esta falhando na validação da requisição ou o teu servidor aonde esta rodando o script esta mal-configurado, não tem como sabermos, de qualquer forma o problema parece de INFRA e não de cõdigo.